# Windows Japanese IME: Disabling Romaji Mode

Tags: windows, keyboard, ime, japanese

Is it possible to disable the romaji input mode in the Japanese IME in Windows so that only the kana input mode is available?

This is possible in other operating systems, for example in Mac OS X, as in the following picture:

[image: Max OS X Japanese IME settings]

Here, the romaji and full-width romaji options can simply be unchecked and will then be disabled.

Can this be done in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a way to disable different input methods as is possible with MacOS, but I have figured out how to stop windows from *constantly* automatically switching input modes.

If you are in Japanese language mode (with the Microsoft IME Japanese logo [like this](https://files.tofugu.com/articles/japanese/2016-04-18-how-to-install-japanese-keyboard/windows10-tooblar-japanese-english-switch.jpg)), you can right-click the `A`, `あ`, or `カ` to open a popover menu.　I found that turning off conversion helped me.

In the end, I switched IME's entirely. Now, I am using [Google's IME](https://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/ime/) because it's more configurable and doesn't arbitrarily change my settings.